# JavaScript running elsewhere but not in MediaWiki:common.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mediawiki

The following code:

```
jQuery( function() {
  var kscript = document.createElement("script");
  kscript.src = 'https://assets-cdn.kf5.com/supportbox/main.js?' + (new Date()).getDay();
  kscript.setAttribute("id","kf5-provide-supportBox");
  kscript.setAttribute("kchat-id","1041075");
  kscript.setAttribute("kf5-domain","airbook.kf5.com");
  kscript.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  s.appendChild(kscript);
});
```

when embedded in a plain HTML page, it works like a charm. It renders an icon and when clicked, triggers an IM dialog.

However, when embedded in **MediaWiki:common.js** it does not work. I can clearly see the  generated and put into the correct position in the  segment. Nevertheless it seems nothing happened.

[Screenshot from DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L88dG.png)

[Test Page from a plain HTML page](https://gaobo.json.love/harness/testkf5.html)

[Test Page from a Wiki page](https://gao.bo/wiki/Special:Random) (In Chinese but content can be ignored anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the JS in common.js loads at a later time,
If you add a setTimeout around the script in your test page you can see it will not load also. In your wiki you can add this in common.js to make it work:

```
(function() {
  var kscript = document.createElement("script");
  kscript.src = 'https://assets-cdn.kf5.com/supportbox/main.js?' + (new Date()).getDay();
  kscript.setAttribute("id","kf5-provide-supportBox");
  kscript.setAttribute("kchat-id","1041075");
  kscript.setAttribute("kf5-domain","airbook.kf5.com");
  kscript.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  s.appendChild(kscript);
  
  isKF5()
  
})();

function isKF5(){

  if (typeof KF5SupportBoxAPI !== 'undefined') {
      KF5SupportBoxAPI.init()
  } else {
    setTimeout( function(){
      isKF5()
    }, 100)
  }
  
}
```